# The life time sales total is not changing on updating the status of the order

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to update the status of quite a few orders in bulk from pending to complete, and hence I am trying to do it in a programmatic way as there is no option in magento backend, for updating the status in bulk by using the method below.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
Mage::init();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100010175');
        //$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true);
        $order->setData('state', "complete");
        $order->setStatus("complete");       
        $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to Complete by our automation tool.', false);
        $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
        $order->save();
```

But when I update the status using the above method, only the status is getting updated to complete. But the order amount is not getting added up to the lifetime sales, that shows up on the dashboard main page.

Can anyone let me know, how the order amount also can be updated to the lifetime sales total, with the updating of the status of the order too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the order amount will be added to life time sales only if the invoice of the order is generated. So you need to create the invoice of the order also.

You can programmatically generate invoice of order by using the code given below.

```
 $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();                
$invoice->register()->capture();
Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($invoice)
            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
            ->save();
$order->addStatusToHistory(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING,'Invoice generated successfully.');
$order->save();
```

Comment: The above code gave me error while trying to create the invoice, for that I used a different code. But the idea that you gave of creating the invoice before changing status, helped me in finding the solution for my answer. Hence I am accepting your answer. Thank You